# what is the difference between NOT(C IMPLIES (A AND B)) and (NOT C IMPLIES (A AND B))?

Tags: logic

Like for the following example: $ (¬A ∧ (B ∨ C)) ↔ ¬(C → (A → B))$

Is this formula satisfiable? And how do I do it? Please explain as much as you can because I'm trying to understand this subject but it seem a bit complicated to me.

Comment: try all of the combinations of truth values for A B C. See if any of true values for the formulas differ, they cannot be equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a hint, it's good to remember that $A \implies B$ is (for most purposes) equivalent to $\lnot A \lor B$. This is true because a truth table shows that $A \implies B$ is false if and only if $A$ is true and $B$ is false. From there, addressing the question in the title:

\begin{align*}
 \lnot C \implies A \land B &\iff \lnot\lnot C \lor (A \land B) \\
 &\iff C \lor (A \land B)
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
 \lnot (C \implies A \land B) &\iff \lnot(\lnot C \lor (A \land B)) \\
 &\iff \lnot\lnot C \land \lnot(A \land B) \\
 &\iff C \land (\lnot A \lor \lnot B)
\end{align*}

I hope this sheds some light on your question.

Comment: I'm sorry but how did you get NOT NOT C? I don't get this leap! And again, is there a difference between ¬(C) and ¬C? like in my example?

Comment: David, $p \implies q$ is logically equivalent to $\neg p \lor q$, so $\neg p \implies q \dashv \vdash \neg \neg p \lor q$

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I get it. How did you know about these things? I'm so lost in my class and my teacher is kinda terrible. Any videos you would recommend or easy to read and understand books? I prefer videos though.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any sources; I learned about these in a textbook-less course. You can post a separate question on StackExchange about which books to consult. If you do ask, you should probably link to this question or mention the source of this problem (textbook, class, etc.)